# HQL for an any association

Tags: hibernate, nhibernate, hql

I'm trying to write HQL for a `Rental` that has many-to-any association `PaymentTypes`.

```
from rental 
where not exists(
    from PaymentTypes pt where pt.Owner = :rental and type = 'Visa'
)
```

`Owner` is a any association where `OwnerId` is `rental.Id` and `OwnerType = 'Rental'`

Unfortunately I can't use `SetEntity` as prefetching the rentals and then calling `SetEntity` will be very costly.

Answer (score 0):

Why not trying a dynamic query like

```
from rental where not exists(from PaymentTypes pt where pt.Owner.id = " + rental.id + " and type = 'Visa')
```

Comment: Unfortunately this is an existing very complex HQL query and I'm trying to just add another condition.